# do i use ci_sessions to store session data

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im developing site for a travel site, in the process when a user searches I do manipulation on the database result then store it in session. Which stores the data in the ci_session  database.  By following this method I'm able to easily filter the data from

```
$this->session->userdata();
```

A normal search which results in 4 hotels the session data goes more than 20kb, in actual server environment it is possible that the result will be more than 200 hotels, i.e. 4000kb data for a single user on each row, in ci_session table.

this process is making the app very slow, What other approach i can follow to make the search result much faster.

Comment: First off re-think why you need 5kb data for a hotel search result. Are you also storing a thumbnail image in there?

Comment: no not thumbnail image but all the necessary data which we show on search result.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the session data in your database. CI Sessions have the ability to handle that. No need to do it yourself.

Read the [chapter in the manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) how to configure it properly. Choose wisely what you write into the "session" since lots of sessiondata in the database *could* make the requests slow if you need them on every site.

Comment: yes I'm following CI_session table, but my search is being too slow.